# Cmake error when genmsg is added to the CMakeLists.txt during message creation

Tags: ros, genmsg, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

During the creation of a .msg file as mentioned in the ros tutorial, I have added genmsg package as well along with std_msgs [ in package.xml and also in CMakeLists.txt at find_package(...) ,catkin_package(...) and generate_messages(...) areas ]. When I catkin_make install after this , a CMake error related to genmsg-cmake  is popping up and when I exclude genmsg from CMakeList file, the error disappeared. Why is it so ? Also , how do I decide on what dependencies to add when creating a .msg file ? Thank you in advance.

---

1. yes , creating ros msg and srv is the tutorial I was referring to.
2. [image: C:\fakepath\1.PNG] - Since the particular example used only std_msgs as a dependency , I was thinking if genmsg could also be added as another dependency ?[ how do we decide which package our created .msg file should depend on ? ]
3. So, after adding genmsg as well ,to the dependency list in CMakeLists.txt , the following error popped up when I catkin_make install ( the last step in creating the message , "common step for msg and srv" as the tutorial mentions. ) [image: C:\fakepath\2.png]

Please let me know if you still require any additional information to clarify . Thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254113/cmake-error-when-genmsg-is-added-to-the-cmakelists.txt-during-message-creation/) by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2017-02-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-09**:
@sam26: please *EDIT* your original question if you want to provide us with more information. Posting answers should only be done if you are *answering* your own question. This is not a regular forum, but a Q&A site. I've merged your update/answer into your question, but please keep it in mind.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-09**:
@sam26: also please **don't** use screenshots for showing us console text. It doesn't make sense. Just copy-paste the text from your console into your question. Then use the *Preformatted Text* button to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, but is [Creating a ROS msg and srv](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) the "ros tutorial" you refer to?

Can you tell us where it asks you to add `genmsg`? I can't find it on that page.

> Also , how do I decide on what dependencies to add when creating a .msg file ? Thank you in advance.

Please see [catkin 0.7.4 documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2 (recommended) » Building messages, services or actions](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_msgs.html) (in addition to the tutorial you linked).

> When I catkin_make install after this , a CMake error related to genmsg-cmake is popping up and when I exclude genmsg from CMakeList file, the error disappeared.

Btw: when asking questions about "errors" it would help if you would include those errors, as we cannot guess what you are seeing, and that makes it *very* hard to help you.

---

Edit:

> 2 . Since the particular example used only `std_msgs` as a dependency , I was thinking if `genmsg` could also be added as another dependency ?

No. `genmsg` is a package that is related to msg code generation, but should not be directly used when creating message *packages*, such as you are doing.

The tutorial also does not ask you to include that package, anywhere.

> how do we decide which package our created .msg file should depend on ?

Well, same as how you decide which package you depend on for other things: which package provides the message definition that you use in your own `.msg` file? For anything from `std_msgs`, specify a dependency on `std_msgs`. For anything you use from `geometry_msgs`, specify a dependency on `geometry_msgs`. Etc.

> 3 . So, after adding `genmsg` as well ,to the dependency list in `CMakeLists.txt`, the following error popped up when I `catkin_make install` ( the last step in creating the message , "common step for msg and srv" as the tutorial mentions. ) [image: C:\fakepath\2.png]

I don't think it makes sense to try and debug this: *don't* add `genmsg` as a dependency when you just want to create your own messages. It's not needed.

Please also see [catkin 0.7.4 documentation » How to do common tasks » Package format 2 (recommended) » Building messages, services or actions](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_msgs.html) for additional information.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0